When and where did the phrase "that sweet, sweet X" originate?
You see it all the time everywhere now, somebody saying something like "I'm going to the store to buy that sweet, sweet sugar." -- but usually it's more non-culinary, like "Press x to jump to the next platform and claim that sweet, sweet extra gold." or "Tell him the truth and get that sweet, sweet revenge."
It's just a really common phrase but I can't figure out where it came from - the usual meme history sites and google searches turn up nothing for me.

Sounds like its derived from the tag line of an old advertisment.

I actually hear the similar Hamlet and R&J Sweets to the sweet and Parting is such sweet sorrow.

I strongly suspect this is something that has only entered English in the last ~10-15 years. I can't find good examples prior to 2010 or so, so I think it's a much newer usage.

I think it's just a (very recent) really simple version of repetitive reduplication like goody-goody, super-duper, la-di-da,...

I can readily find song sheets from circa 1901, and even a translation of Erasmus (unsure the date of translation) that include this construction. I suspect it is quite old.

Well, there's Fairburn Senr's. laughable Song Book for 1812 with the lyrics to Oh that Kiss! That Sweet, Sweet Kiss! but after that the repetition dropped out of favour until a revival got underway in recent decades.

Thanks for these. I was able to find some more describing romantic / culinary / spiritual topics that way in the past so I believe you're right; refining my search, I was also able to find references pre-1900 (e.g., Bram Stoker's Dracula). I think the usage feels somewhat different now, but still, close enough.

Things like this tend to go in and out of style. In the old days it would often be due to a popular writer or politician using the phrase, now it would probably come from a social media influencer. Imagine if Taylor Swift decided to put "sweet, sweet" in a song, all the kids would be saying it.

Yeah, I was wondering if the more modern usage which tends to be a bit less "sincere" than the older usages stemmed from an identifiable "Taylor Swift" moment, but it seems not.:)

Regarding the usage as a meme, the first thing that comes to my mind is the Simpsons episode "Homer Badman", where Homer talks about "sweet, sweet candy": https://getyarn.io/yarn-clip/917e2e10-6d04-46ff-843b-41c134130f7a But it probably betrays my age that I think this is a possible "modern" source...

There are certainly uses of "sweet, sweet" preceding Homer Badman in 1994, e.g. John Howard Payne's 1823 song Home! Sweet Home!. But the Simpsons sounds a likely populariser of it.

H. Davidson, in a letter to a recently widowed friend, dated July 16, 1755, reprinted in The Missionary Magazine (November 18, 1802):  has this instance: "Endeavour, both of you, to mingle that sweet, sweet word with faith, applying it to yourselves as really spoken to you." ...

... And from Mathew Stevenson, "A Glimiring Glimpse of Heaven," in Occasions Off-spring, or, Poems upon Severall Occasions (1645): "Or is it beauty, whose Celestiall fire, / Blowes up that Aetna of the worlds desire? / Lyes it else in Revenge that sweet, sweet case, / Of injuries; Noe, noe, tis none of these."

The repetition for the emphatic has been around since Middle English but accessible examples are difficult to come by but we have
In "The Dramatik Works of Beaumont and Fletcher v.8" By Francis Beaumont 1778, we find

Isab. Can I chuse but love thee?  Thou art my Martyr; thou hast
suffer’d for me,  My sweet, sweet Rugio

The only difference from your “sweet, sweet” is is the nuance of its modern use.
For further reading “Tracing The Development Of An Old Old Story: Intensificatory Repetition In English” Victorina González-Díaz First published: 10 November 2017
https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/1467-968X.12114
Abstract

The present paper explores the synchronic distribution and historical development of an intensificatory construction that has so far received little attention in previous literature on English; i.e. what Huddleston and Pullum (2002) label as INTENSIFICATORY REPETITION (e.g. old old story, long long way). Synchronically, the paper records the existence of two functional subtypes of repetitive intensification (affection and degree) and expands previous accounts by showing the functional versatility of the degree intensificatory subtype. At the diachronic level, the paper dates the establishment of (degree) intensificatory repetition to the Late Modern English (LModE) period. It also suggests that (a) intensificatory affection was the first repetitive (sub)type to develop in the language, and (b) that its collocational expansion from Early Modern English (EModE) onwards may have paved the way for the establishment of its degree intensification counterpart.

